# how to write a recurrent auto associative network?

Tags: neural-networks

I need to write a recurrent autoassociative network in python . I have read *Explorations in Parallel Distributed Processing: A Handbook o f Models,Programs, and Exercises* but I can't understand how are the activation updating cycles written. any information about this would be helpful. specially if i could find an algorithm for this .

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask questions about the implementation of ML algorithms